# Как перерендерить компонент с новыми initialValues?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Есть такой код:

```
<DataForm initialValues={data} />
```

Компоненты принимает `initalValues`, это дефолтные значения для внутренних полей компонента.
Мне нужно, что когда я запрашиваю новые данные с сервера, то пропса `data` обновлялась в компоненте, но так как это `initalValues`, то ничего не срабатывает, новые данные игнорируются.

Как решить данную проблему?

Доступ к `DataForm` компоненту нет, т.к. это компонент из либы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете просто обновлять `key` у компонента, чтобы создавался новый `instance`.

```
const [formKey, setFormKey] = useState();

const extraRef = useRef({
  isMounted: false,
});

// ...

useEffect(() => {
  if (extraRef.current.isMounted) {
    setFormKey(Math.random());
  } else {
    extraRef.current.isMounted = true;
  }
}, [data]);

// ...

return (
  <DataForm key={formKey} initialValues={data} />
);
```

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло